# Google Calendar: how do I create a new calendar in Android?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar

I was wondering how to create a new calendar with dates in Google Calendar.

I ask because I have gone to settings but only see the following page (with no buttons to add, view, or modify):

[image: calendars]

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like it's not possible to create a new calendar from the Android app directly, instead of from [the web app](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r). Again, not sure about a 3rd-party app solution.